# Where to close the cursor , when using an adapter and an asynctask?

Tags: android, cursor, android-asynctask, adapter

I am using `AsyncTask` to retrieve some information from a database.
Hence inside the `doInBackground` method, I write the following code:

```java
dbhandler = new DbHandler(TestActivity.this);
db = dbhandler.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT sys_id as _id,statuses,user,created_at FROM status ORDER BY sys_id desc", null);
Log.d(TAG, "cursor got count: " + cursor.getCount());
return cursor;
```

I use this cursor in the `postExecute` method which is:

```cs
adapter = new TimelineAdapter(TestActivity.this, cursor);
listTimeline.setAdapter(adapter);
dbhandler.close();
Log.d(TAG, "Getting here ...");
```

Now the problem is: if I keep this as it is, I get an error in `logcat`, saying that the cursor has to be closed. But when I write `cursor.close()` in `postExcecute()` method, I am not able to retrieve a single record though my cursor has a finite count.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Activity handle it, by calling `startManagingCursor()`.